# Pandas mapping data from 2 dataframe with different column names

Tags: python, pandas

I tried to map these two dataframes but I failed. Maybe because the column names and it's value is a little bit different.

I wanted to create a new dataframe like in the dfNew.

### df

```
Employee ID Employee Name   Activity Month
A0001       John Smith      Apr-19
A0002       Will Cornor     Apr-19
A0001       John Smith      May-19
A0003       David Teo       May-19
A0001       John Smith      May-19
A0002       Will Cornor     Jun-19
A0001       John Smith      Jun-19
```

### df2

```
Month       Bonus
2019-04-01  5000
2019-05-01  4000
2019-06-01  6000
```

### dfNew

```
Employee ID Employee Name   Activity Month  Bonus
A0001       John Smith      Apr-19          5000
A0002       Will Cornor     Apr-19          5000
A0001       John Smith      May-19          4000
A0003       David Teo       May-19          4000
A0001       John Smith      May-19          4000
A0002       Will Cornor     Jun-19          6000
A0001       John Smith      Jun-19          6000
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) fr change format of `datetimes`, so possible [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
s = df2.set_index(df2['Month'].dt.strftime('%b-%y'))['Bonus']
df1['Bonus'] = df1['Activity Month'].map(s)
print (df1)
  Employee     ID Employee Name Activity Month  Bonus
0    A0001   John         Smith         Apr-19   5000
1    A0002   Will        Cornor         Apr-19   5000
2    A0001   John         Smith         May-19   4000
3    A0003  David           Teo         May-19   4000
4    A0001   John         Smith         May-19   4000
5    A0002   Will        Cornor         Jun-19   6000
6    A0001   John         Smith         Jun-19   6000
```

Or use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) for new column with remove original:

```
df2['Activity Month'] = df2.pop('Month').dt.strftime('%b-%y')
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='Activity Month', how='left')
```

Comment: I got an error about the datatype. Can u help me fix it?
...
AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Comment: I tried to convert it to datetime but then this one came out ---- ValueError: time data 'Apr-19' does not match format '%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f' (match)

Comment: @FirdhausSaleh - so there is same format `Apr-19` in both DataFrames? Then remove `.dt.strftime('%b-%y')` in both solutions.

Comment: Or convert both datetimes to same format like `df1['Activity Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Activity Month'], format='%b-%y').dt.strftime('%b-%y')` and `df2['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Month'], format='%b-%y').dt.strftime('%b-%y')`

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer for now based on @jezrael suggestion

```
df1['Activity Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Activity Month'], format='%b-%y').dt.strftime('%b-%y')

df2['Month'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Month'], format='%Y-%m-%d').dt.strftime('%b-%y')

df2['Activity Month'] = df2.pop('Month')
df1 = df1.merge(df2, on='Activity Month', how='left')
```